# Avoid exposing private repos in pyproject.toml when using poetry

Tags: pypi, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I am using two private repos in order to install Python packages. As far as I understand it from the docs (https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#install-dependencies-from-a-private-repository), when using `poetry`, these repos must be specified in the `pyproject.toml` file.

This has the drawback, that I can't commit this file to VCS as I don't want expose any internal server names.

Is it possible to define these repositories somewhere else (e.g. environment variables)?

```
# pyproject.toml

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "my_private_repo_1"
url = "https://my_private_repo1.com/simple"
default = true

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "my_private_repo_2"
url = "https://my_private_repo2.com/simple"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `url` for a private repository can be set using `poetry config`. For the example above this would look like:

```
poetry config repositories.my_private_repo_1 https://my_private_repo1.com/simple
poetry config repositories.my_private_repo_2 https://my_private_repo2.com/simple
```

The `pyproject.toml` then only needs to include the repository names, so can be edited to remove the URLs:

```
# pyproject.toml

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "my_private_repo_1"
default = true

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "my_private_repo_2"
```

Links to docs:

- https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#repositoriesname
- https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#adding-a-repository

Comment: OK, that would not reveal server names. However, committing this to GitHub wouldn't make sense either. People who fork the repo won't use my internal repos.

Comment: Ah, not sure if there is a poetry solution to your question in that case. It is my understanding that the `[[tool.poetry.source]]` directives must be present in `pyproject.toml` if packages must be retrieved from repositories other than the default (PyPI).

Comment: I created a feature request at https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5958.

Comment: [PDM](https://pdm.fming.dev/) recently solved that issue.